# Theft and restitution: What are the situations when the thief pays back more than the value stolen?

Tags: halacha

Is there a simple outline of the cases in which a thief pays back just the value stolen, and in what situations restitution is more than the amount stolen?

Comment: Much of this is discussed in Bava Kamma https://dafyomi.co.il/bkama/insites/bk-dt-065.htm

Comment: A robber (i.e. a confrontationally violent robber) pays the amount stolen. A thief (i.e. a sneak thief) pays double. One who steals and slaughters/sells cattle or sheep pays 5 or 4 times, respectively. A guardian of an object (e.g. I have been paid to look after someone else's sheep) has the same law as the actual thief / robber, i.e. if the guardian claims he was robbed but actually stole the object himself, he pays once, if he claims the object was thieved but actually took it himself, he pays twice (where he swore to his claim).